# How to make a Password protected cocoa desktop app

Tags: cocoa

How would you go about creating a password protected cocoa desktop app? (on the mac)

i.e. do not allow access to any screen unless password has been entered.

Answer (score 1):

Show the password dialog modally when the app starts up. For example, in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`, get an `NSWindow` containing the password box, and call [`-[NSApplication runModalForWindow:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/runModalForWindow%3a). You'll then dismiss the modal password box if the user put the correct password.